# html Regex can't select content between quote tags

Tags: html, regex

I need to remove `[quote]` tag while keep content, however I tried many times but don't know why I can't select content between them.

```
[b]List of questions[/b]

[quote]
1. Questions 1
2. Questions 2
3. Questions 3
4. Questions 4
5. Questions 5
[/quote]
```

This regex works

```
\s*\[b\](.+?)\[/b\]\s*\[quote\]
```

While this code doesn't work

```
\s*\[b\](.+?)\[/b\]\s*\[quote\](.*?)\[/quote\]
```

I appreciate any helps.

Comment: Because the dot by default doesn't match the newline `\n` character (Line Feed). To change this default behaviour, you need to switch the s (singleline) modifier on, or, if not available, to use `[\s\S]` in place of the dot. In your particular case, and if you are sure that there's no opening square brackets between your quote tags, you can also use `[^\[]`.

Comment: Thanks @CasimiretHippolyte It worked for me.